# React Native: Setting up local environment issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

New to development, trying to get my development environment setup - any ideas as to how to fix this issue?

Command Entered: npm install -g expo-cli

Error, see below:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/expo
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/.expo-uXoQfr9A
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/bin/expo' -> '/usr/local/bin/.expo-uXoQfr9A'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/bin/expo' -> '/usr/local/bin/.expo-uXoQfr9A'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/bin/expo',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/.expo-uXoQfr9A'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cain/.npm/_logs/2022-02-02T19_04_42_626Z-debug.log
```

Comment: did you install the expo cli?

Comment: @JamieGarcia when entering in 'npm install expo-cli'

I get the following warnings:

npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

There are more
67 vulnerabilities (55 moderate, 10 high, 2 critical)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the directory NPM is trying to write has restricted access (/usr/local/bin). It's a common issue and can be easily fixed by reinstalling NPM using Node Version Manager or manually changing NPM's default directory.

See more here: [NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

Comment: Hey Aitwar, it seems as though you're right. When reinstalling node.js - node.js & npm are installed to /usr/local/bin/(node/npm).

I think I will need to change NPM's default directory manually

Comment: would you be able to clarify what this is asking me to do?

Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

Unsure how to Open a /.profile in Terminal

Comment: @Cain You have to use some editor like vim/nano or following snippet: `echo 'export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile`. This will add required line to your .profile automatically.

Comment: @Cain Could you mark this answer as an accepted one? If it works for you, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The -g flag means you're trying to install the npm package globally (which would require sudo permission in linux).

If you're okay with a local install (which should be fine), nagivate to the project directory then run `npm install --no-save` to install expo-cli into the project folder.

Since it's not a dependency of the project itself, it doesn't need to be saved to package.json (hence the --no-save flag).